# What could go wrong with sending input to /dev/tty?

Tags: shell, terminal, tty, readline, ioctl

My setup entails sending inputs to another terminal program running Bash in the same machine and same X session. I'm using [ttyecho](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/) for that which, to put it short, sends input to `/dev/tty/[id]`, effectively performing it "remotely".

I don't claim to understand exactly how the low-level `ioctl` calls are executed but ttyecho works almost always. Sometimes, though, seemingly at random, the input is apparently not processed and results into nothing; when that happens I usually hear a bell "error sound" (sounds like a water drop), so I've been assuming something has gone wrong with the input.

Here's the question: how can the input to `/dev/tty` somehow fail at times? Are there alternatives for ensuring the input I am sending to another terminal program is **always** processed? I've been thinking of trying out `tmux`'s `send-keys` if I don't find a solution using the bare Bash shell, but not sure if it would get rid of the problem.

Note: Since I am sending inputs to a terminal running Bash, I also consider this could be `readline` related rather than an input problem. Either way, I'm out of my depth when it comes to figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: When it fails, are you trying to send very long lines (more than 512 bytes without an Enter)?

Comment: No, the failed lines are as common as any other. I've not been able to notice any correlation from the problem to the input and this comes up fairly often.

Comment: Are you sending any non-EN-US/ASCII characters or anything like embedded control characters like newlines, carriage returns, etc. (anything with a decimal value < 32 or > 126). The newline or tab should be OK, but the other things can cause problems - especially if there are any ESC characters present which can cause subsequent characters to be interpreted as escape sequences to control the terminal itself.

Comment: The text I'm sending is just plain characters. They are Bash commands I'm sending to execute in a remote terminal.